# Cant web deploy web application from team city

Tags: teamcity, web-deployment, webdeploy

Im having a bit of trouble web deploying from my CI server teamcity.I can however do a web deploy through visual studio.

I get the following error 
Open in IDE

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4276,
>   5): error ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE: Web deployment task failed.
>   (Could not connect to the remote computer ("destinationserver"). On
>   the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that
>   the required process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started. 
>   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

and this is my configuration in team city 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzQOr.jpg)

i have also opened up port 8172 so i dont think it is a permissions issue and checked the username and pass is correct

So what i dont understand is why i am able to publish locally but not from the CI?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: It makes sense to trun the same command on the TeamCity agent machine, in the same directory and with the same environment. Try these troubleshooting steps: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Common+Problems#CommonProblems-BuildfailsorbehavesdifferentlyinTeamCitybutnotlocally

Answer (score 0):

I solve this replacing the IP address of the destination host with the DNS name and adding this parameter to the deployment:

```
/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://%TargetServer%/MsDeploy.axd?site=%SiteName%
```